# Getting google prettify to work with dynamic views blogger template

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, blogs, blogger, google-code-prettify

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1909814/560302) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696361/560302) , both previous solutions from stack overflow but both of these solutions are not working with Dynamic Views Template of Blogger. Can you please help to get this working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110694/can-i-google-code-prettify-only-a-portion-of-the-page-run-a-javascript-functio

Comment: just read your question properly, sorry! posting a real answer now...

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540009/prettyprint-doesnt-get-called-on-page-load/14659603#14659603

Answer (score 3):

Wrote a blog post on **Easy Syntax Highlighting for Blogs**

http://blog.jpillora.com/2012/06/easy-syntax-highlighting-for-blogs.html

Currently running on blogger, though I haven't tested it on all browsers though I can't see why it wouldn't work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: where should I include following line
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jpillora.com/js/jp-prettify.js"></script>` in the post or in the template

Comment: Just added it to my dynamic views template and removed it from my posts and it works fine. Though both the blog and js file are on sub-domains of mine, not sure if that affects what google allows.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this below stackoverflow answers, to add that Google code pretifier to blogger..

Adding google prettifier synatx highlighter is very easy..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27579776

also refer this following documentation.

[how to add Syntax Highlighter For Blogger Using Google Prettify](http://blog.smarttutorials.net/2014/12/syntax-highlighter-blogger-using-google.html)

add below code just before  tag...

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

add your code between

```
<pre class="prettyprint">...</pre>
```